# Error while rebuilding tcl 8.5 to disabling threadings

Tags: compiling, source-packages, tcl

Im on installation of Squert Dashboard for suricata on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS

Before install Squert I need to install Sguil (sgweel), sguil need tcl 8.3 (or better) and I found in source the current version of tcl is 8.5 so I installed it and run my installation on.

But when I run  sguild it say me is not comptabile with tcl threadings,

```
ERROR: This version of tcl was compile with threading enabled. Sguil is NOT compatible with threading.
```

so I searched and I found one say we need to rebuild the package with no threading.

I deleted line "--enable-threads \" in debian/rules file but when I want to rebuild the packakge with "debuild -us -uc" command, it say me :

```
dh_makeshlibs: failing due to earlier errors
debian/rules:121 : la recette pour la cible « override_dh_makeshlibs » a échouée
make[1]: *** [override_dh_makeshlibs] Erreur 2
make[1] : on quitte le répertoire « /root/tcl/tcl8.5-8.5.19 »
debian/rules:26 : la recette pour la cible « binary » a échouée
make: *** [binary] Erreur 2
dpkg-buildpackage: erreur: fakeroot debian/rules binary a produit une erreur de sortie de type 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

in english :

```
dh_makeshlibs: failing due to earlier errors
debian/rules:121 : the recipe for the target « override_dh_makeshlibs » failed
make[1]: *** [override_dh_makeshlibs] Error 2
make[1] : we exit the directory « /root/tcl/tcl8.5-8.5.19 »
debian/rules:26 : the recipe for the target « binary » failed
make: *** [binary] Error 2
dpkg-buildpackage: error: fakeroot debian/rules binary make an error of type 2
debuild: fatal error at line 1376:
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -D -us -uc failed
```

If you have an idea or another way for install Squert for Suricata on Ubuntu 16.x I'll take it.

Maybe I need to do my installation on tcl 8.3...

Answer (score 0):

You have to install two packages:

```
apt-get install zlib1g-dev debhelper
```

After:

```
dpkg-buildpackage
debuild -us -uc
```